# Fast/low-memory method to parse first two columns in a large csv file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, csv, text-parsing

I'm parsing a large csv files - about 500 meg (many rows, many columns). I only need the first two columns (so up to the second comma on each line).  Also, multiple threads need access to this file at the same time, so I can't take an exclusive lock.

What's the fastest/least memory consuming approach to this problem?  What classes/methods should I be looking at?  I assume that I should stay as low-level as possible - reading character by character, line by line?

Perhaps this is a way to allow simultaneous access?

```
using ( var filestream = new FileStream( filePath , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) )
{
     using ( var reader = new StreamReader( filestream ) )
     {
       ...
     }
}
```

**Edit**
Decided to check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx
which seems to give me the ability to read just two columns and then skip to the next line.
They also have some benchmarks showing fast performance and low memory profile.

Comment: as you need to work with a stream, you need to have a lock on the line at least. otherwise: a thread takes a line to start reading, second thread moves stream to new line ... et voila ...

Comment: @Andreas - could you take a look at the code I posted to the orginal question.  Does this get around the issue of simultaneous access?

Comment: simultaneous access depends a lot on what you're doing with the file.  If they are both only reading, then you're in good shape.  If one of them needs to write to the file, then there are race conditions and you'll need to coordinate your reads and writes carefully.

Comment: @Dan - thanks!  It seems I'm in good shape because I'm only ever reading from these files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want low memory, you'll probably use a StreamReader and ReadLine by line.

In a similar case the other day, I was able to skip the first 20,000,000 lines in a 500 MB file and build a string (using StringBuilder) for the next 1,000,000 lines in about 7 seconds.

Comment: i would suggest using `.Read()` as it doesn't read the whole line - just char by char. this may be better for low-memory-consumption :)

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: It also says "fast". :-(

Comment: For that you need to measure :) depending on the length of the line I would still give .Read a better change to win the performance-challenge :)

Comment: @Andreas: The I/O and memory use would be (about) the same. The size of 1 line is probably insignificant and the StreamReader is likely to cache a lot more. Using Read() will add some CPU overhead.

Comment: @Henk: thanks for the enlightenment :) will do some measuring tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the file contains ASCII encoded text (would be typical for csv), your best bet may be to use Stream directly and the [Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) method, which allows you to read into a pre-allocated buffer.  This has a few advantages:

1. You only allocate a buffer once, whereas ReadLine() will create a new String for every line.
2. You don't have to perform the Unicode conversion for the entire line; you can either do this only for the portion up to the second comma or (if you're severely time-constrained), you can write your own numeric parser that operates on the ASCII string data in the buffer (I'm sure there are well-documented algorithms for doing this.)  This is assuming you need numeric data, of course.

Additional methods you'll likely need include the [ASCII Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) methods, particularly `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.

Comment: You're probably right about the buffer and more so about the encoding. But it's not so clear, if you use ReadLine and keep the lifetime of the strings short there should be very little GC overhead. And for more complicated scenarios it would be much easier.

Comment: @Henk, I agree, using ReadLine is definitely simpler and the GC should be fairly efficient at handling the turnover in String instances (and associated buffers, including the buffer used to store the original ASCII for the line before being encoded as Unicode).  It's probably worth implementing using ReadLine first and measuring the performance; if it's not sufficient, then this approach should be faster by a fair amount.

Comment: @Dan - thanks for the excellent write-up!  I'm leaning towards Read because the buffer is compelling.  In my case, I can actually predict the length of the first two columns of the file (I might overestimate by a few characters, but that is no big deal)

Comment: So once I call Read(), how do I get to the next line? =)  hopefully not using ReadLine otherwise that defeats the point of using Read.

Comment: On a side note, a GC Gen0 collection would likely be triggered several times with the ReadLine method, but the heap should require minimal or no compaction each time (unless there is activity on other Threads in Gen0.)  For a 500M ASCII file, you would need at least 1.5GB over the course of the processing, with additional overhead per line (so a file with more rows would consume more than one with more columns.)

Comment: @SFun28, you'll need to manually manage reading the buffer in chunks and checking for the end-of-line character (or characters, if it's CRLF (0x0D, 0x0A)).  This will require management of a buffer 'current index' and occasional movement of data in the buffer to accommodate partial reads (when you reach the end of the chunk and need to continue processing), so it's definitely more work than using ReadLine.

Comment: @Dan - thanks! I was hoping for some easy way to read a certain number of characters, then just fast-forward to the next line, rinse, repeat